# How to upsert/Delete the DB2 source table data using Pyspark/SQL/DataFrames SPARK RDD's?

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run the upsert/delete some of the values in DB2 database source table, which is a existing table on DB2. Is it possible using Pyspark/Spark SQL/Dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way for update/delete in relational database using Pyspark job, but there are workarounds.

(1) You can create a identical empty table (secondary table) in relational database and insert data into secondary table using pyspark job, and write a DML trigger that would perform desired DML operation on your primary table.

(2) You can create a dataframe (eg. a) in spark that would be copy of your existing relational table and merge existing table dataframe with current dataframe(eg. b) and create a new dataframe(eg. c) that would be having latest changes. Now truncate the relational database table and reload with spark latest changes dataframe(c).

These is just a workaround and not a optimal solution for huge amount of data.